# Using dd command to download mtd block

Tags: linux, embedded, dd, busybox

How to use dd command to download mtd block from embedded Linux-based device?

```
# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
...
mtd3: 003a0000 00010000 "DRTI2"
```

I need download mtd3 block, so

```
dd if=/dev/mtdblock3 bs=BYTES count=BLOCKS | nc 192.168.1.30 5555
```

What should be correct **bs** and **count** values and how to calculate it?
Size is '003a0000' and erasesize (erase block size) is '00010000' in hex values.

Comment: Do you want full mtdblock3? If so, just do `cat /dev/mtdblock3 | nc 192.168.1.30 5555`.

Comment: @siblynx Yes, I need full mtdblock3. But is it possible do this with **dd** command?

Comment: `dd` and `cat` are equal if you want to read full mtdblock3. With **dd** it will be: `dd if=/dev/mtdblock3 | nc 192.168.1.30 5555`. Just omit optional `bs=` and `count=`.

Comment: @siblynx, if to use **dd** with `bs` and `count` operands, is this correct code: `dd if=/dev/mtdblock3 bs=65536 count=58 | nc 192.168.1.30 5555` I have converted hexadecimal values to bytes.

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dd` and `cat` are equal if you want to read full mtdblock3. With dd it will be: `dd if=/dev/mtdblock3 | nc 192.168.1.30 5555`. Just omit optional `bs=` and `count=`.